# A proof that if a set is closed if and only if it contains all its limite points

Tags: general-topology, analysis, solution-verification

> A subset $\def\R{\mathbb{R}} A \subseteq \R$ is called closed if its complement $\R−A$ is open. Prove that $A$ is closed if and only if $A$ contains all of its limit points.

Proof：
$A$ is closed $\implies$ $A$ contains all its limit points

Suppose $\alpha$ is a limit point of $A$ and $\alpha$ is not in $A$. Then it must be in the complement of $A$ that is the open set $\R - A$. Then because if $\alpha$ is the limit point of $A$, then for every open interval $J$ that contains $\alpha$, there exists some $x\in J$ and $x \in A - \{\alpha\}$. Further, it's no need to specify $x \in A - \{\alpha\}$ and can only write $x \in A$ because $\alpha$ is not in $A$, $x$ certainly can't be $\alpha$. Therefore, because $\alpha$ is the limit point not in $A$, it should have the property that: for every open interval $J$ that contains $\alpha$, there exists some $x \in J $ and $x \in A$

In particular,  I can choose the open interval to be $\R - A$ and indeed $\alpha \in \R - A$, and if $\alpha$ is the limit point of A, it also should satisfy this special case. However, because $\R - A$ is the complement of $A$, $ A \cap \R - A = \varnothing$. Hence,  $x \in \R - A$ and $x \in A$ are not satisfied. Therefore, $\alpha$ is not the limit point of $A$. This means that $A$ doesn't have limit point that is not in $A$, and $A$ contains all its limit points.

$A$ contains all its limit points $\implies$ $A$ is closed

Given the definition of the open interval: $\forall x\in U\, \exists\epsilon>0\, \forall y\in \R\colon\, |x-y|< \epsilon \Rightarrow y \in U$ which has the same effect as $\forall x\in U\, \exists\epsilon>0\, \forall y\in \R \colon\, |x-y|\geq \epsilon$ or $y\in U$

Because $A$ contains all its limit points, then choose the largest one and denote it as $t$ which is not in $\R - A$ and less than every element in the "right part" of $\R - A$, and $t$ can be the limit point of both $A$ and $\R - A$. Suppose the elements in $\R - A$ is $z$ because $t$ is the limit point of $\R - A$. $\forall \delta >0,\, \exists z\in \R - A, 0 < z-t < \delta$ (no absolute value because $t$ is the largest limit point of $A$ and all elements in $\R - A$ can only "approach" $z$ from the right. Thus $z-t < \delta \implies z < t+\delta,\, \forall \delta>0$ and this is the definition of the infimum of the right part of $\R - A$.

Then due to Archimedean property, there exists $\frac{1}{n}$ such that $z-t \geq \frac{1}{n}>0$.
Similarly, choose the smallest limit point of set $A$ and denote $u$, by the same step above then get $u-z\geq \frac{1}{n}>0$

Finally $\forall z\in \R - A,\, \exists\epsilon = \frac{1}{n}>0\, \forall r\in \R\colon\, |z-r| \geq \epsilon$ or $z\in U$. For the real numbers, they are either in $\R - A$, they are not in $\R - A$, or they are $t$ and $u$. The last two situations satisfy the requirement $|z-r| \geq \epsilon$. For $t$ and $u$ because there are limit points of $A$ and contained in $A$, so it's impossible to have $z=t$ nor $z=u$. Thus $|z-t| \geq \frac{1}{n} =\epsilon$ and $|z-t| \geq \frac{1}{n} =\epsilon$, and for $r$ that are not in $\R - A$, they also satisfy this. As a result, the set $\R - A$ is open. Hence, $A$ is closed.